# UISwitch value inside a nib does not being updated

Tags: ios, swift

My switch is inside of a nib which is inside of a tableview header. When I click the switch it only does the `pushSwitch.isOn` and not `!pushSwitch.isOn`. It only gives me the values inside of the pushSwitch and doesn't seem to go inside of `!pushSwitch.isOn`
Thanks

```
protocol PhoneNotificationHeaderViewDelegate: class {
    func copyPreferredSettingsRequested()
    func textNotificationSwitchTapped()
    func pushNotificationSwitchTapped()
}

class PhoneNotificationHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var pushSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var copyPreferredSettingsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationView: UIView!

weak var delegate: PhoneNotificationHeaderViewDelegate?

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func textNotificationSwitchTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate?.textNotificationSwitchTapped()
}

@IBAction func pushNotificationSwitchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.delegate?.pushNotificationSwitchTapped()
}

@IBAction func copyPreferredSettingsButtonTapped() {
    self.delegate?.copyPreferredSettingsRequested()
}

override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        print("backgroundColor")
    }
}
```

Here is my switch inside my VC:

```
extension PhoneNotificationViewController: PhoneNotificationHeaderViewDelegate {
func pushNotificationSwitchTapped() {

    guard let phoneNotificationHeader = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed("PhoneNotificationHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? PhoneNotificationHeaderView else {
        return
    }

    if phoneNotificationHeader.pushSwitch.isOn{
        //Disable Firebase from sending
        Globals.sharedInstance.pushStatus = true
        phoneNotificationHeader.pushSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }else{
        Globals.sharedInstance.pushStatus = false
        phoneNotificationHeader.pushSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    self.refreshUI()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "a nib which is inside of a tableview header". Every time you load a nib by saying `loadNibNamed`, you get a fresh copy of the view that it contains. So every time you call `pushNotificationSwitchTapped` you are a getting a *whole new switch* fresh from the nib, and sticking it in your interface. That is probably not what you intend! And of course the switch comes from the nib in only one state, namely the state that you set it in the nib editor: it is On.

You need to abandon completely this incorrect architecture based on a misapprehension about what a nib is. You should load the nib *once*, and from then on you should refer to the *switch* by talking to the switch itself, the one that is now in your interface.